# F# Iterate a Seq of KeyValuePair and print all Key, Values. Then failwithf if the list is not empty

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequence, seq

I have a Seq of KeyValuePair that I want to print all the keys and values and after that I want to fail if the list is not empty and a variable value is true (failOnError).

My try is the following but it always fails after the 1st iteration printing the 1 KeyValuePair.

```
Seq.map(fun kvp -> 
               printfn "Key: %s" kvp.Key
               printfn "Value: %s" kvp.Value
               kvp)
    |> fun seq ->
        if not (Seq.isEmpty seq) && failOnError
        then
            failwithf "There is Errors see above messages"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sequences in F# are *lazy*: they will only iterate through as many elements as necessary. Some operations will require getting all the elements of the sequence, like `Seq.toList`. But `Seq.map` is not one of them: when you do `Seq.map`, you still have a lazy sequence that has not yet gone through any elements. And `Seq.isEmpty` will only iterate through *one* element, since that's all it takes to prove that the sequence wasn't empty.

What you probably want is to replace `Seq.isEmpty` with `Seq.toList |> List.isEmpty`. Then you'll end up iterating though all the elements. Note, too, that you'll end up iterating through all the elements *whether or not* your `failOnError` value is true. If you wanted to print the keys and values *only* if `failOnError` is false, then you should change the order of your `if` statement: `if failOnError && not (seq |> Seq.toList |> List.isEmpty)`.

Comment: Hi @rmunn thanks for the complete answer and the provided background on F# Seq I see the problem now and your proposal do the thing :)